# Navigate with parameters in latest NativeScript with Angular and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular, navigation, nativescript

I want to navigate to another page with parameters, but I can't seem to find documentation that explains it well. I am using routes. Here is an example of my routes.

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { nsProvideRouter } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { MainPage } from './pages/main/main.component';
import { DetailsPage } from './pages/details/details.component';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: "", component: MainPage },
    { path: "details", component: DetailsPage }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    nsProvideRouter(routes, {})
];
```

I want to navigate to the DetailsPage with the parameters of what was selected on MainPage. Here is an excerpt of MainPage:

```
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Entity } from '../../shared/entity/entity';

@Component({
    selector: "main",
    templateUrl: "pages/main/main.html",
    styleUrls: ["pages/main/main-common.css", "pages/main/main.css"]
})
export /**
 * MainPage
 */
class MainPage {

    constructor(private _page: Page, private _router: Router) { }

    onNavigate(selectedItem: Entity) {
        // Can't figure out how to get selectedItem to details…
        this._router.navigate(["/details"]);
    };
}
```

Inserted: Below I added the detail class.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Entity } from '../../shared/entity/entity';
import { EntityModel } from '../../shared/entity/entity.model';

@Component({
    selector: "detail",
    templateUrl: "pages/detail/detail.html",
    styleUrls: ["pages/detail/detail-common.css", "pages/detail/detail.css"],
    providers: [EntityModel] 
})
export /**
 * DetailPage
 */
class DetailPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    entity: Entity;

    private _paramSubcription: any;

    constructor( private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private _entityModel: EntityModel ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("detail ngOnInit was called.");
        let entityName: string;
        this._paramSubcription = this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => entityName = params['id']);
        this.entity = this._entityModel.entityNamed(entityName);
    };

    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this._paramSubcription) {
            this._paramSubcription.unsubscribe();
        };
    };
}
```

Here is the template for Detail:

```
<ActionBar [title]="entity.name"></ActionBar>
<ListView [items]="entity.items">
    <Template let-item="item">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label [text]="item.name"></Label>
            <Label [text]="item.description"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Template>
</ListView>
```

I have found classes like a `NavigationContext` and methods `navigateTo` and `navigateFrom`, but I haven't figured out how to send the `NavigationContext` to the `Page`. Or if it even should be sent that way. So the question is, what is the best way to use `Routing` to navigate to another page (not a dialog) and pass parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to express that you should have parameters in this route:

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: "", component: MainPage },
    { path: "details/:id", component: DetailsPage }
];
```

then, you can pass it that way:

```
this._router.navigate(["/details", selectedItem.id]);
```

in your `DetailsPage` you can get the parameters as an observable with the `ActivatedRoute` service.

Comment: I tried this solution and once I changed the method call to put a forward slash in front of "details" so in code it is `this._router.navigate(["/details", selectedItem.id]);` the new page displays. However even though the screen would display I noticed the ngOnInit was not getting called. After some debugging I found that `expandPathsWithParams(segment, routes, paths, outlet, allowRedirects)` in `apply_redirects.js` is throwing a `NoMatch` exception. So the constructor runs but ngOnInit does not.

Comment: when the page is displayed, does the `ngOnInit` getting invoked?. can you add the `DetailsPage` component here?

Comment: ngOnInit is not getting invoked. Before it is called there is an exception thrown in `expandPathsWithParams` in the angular core code. I have added the detail component and template code. The only other thing to know is that I changed line in main.ts to this._router.navigate(["/details", selectedItem.name]);.

Comment: I was able to prove this works first by a test project and then by cutting practically everything out of the the source and target pages. I am currently attempting to get all the functionality back in and having various problems. But I am checking this as correct anyway. Thanks.

Comment: +Doron Any chance you can link to docs or any explanation for ActivatedRoute?